# Getting coordinates of mouse click from frame that has some content drawed in

Tags: java, dictionary, mouselistener

My basic problem is that i have an internal frame that has a map showed in.And i want to get coordinates of clicks on that map so i can draw a Waypoints to that map.But basically what i get is nothing. getX and getY returns coordinates only when i click somewhere outside of that map(inside internal frame).
Adding the waypoints manually works normal.
Heres my code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.GeoPosition;


import soft.MapDrawer;
import soft.MapView;


import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Box;

public class MainWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenu MenuBasicActions;
    private JInternalFrame mapFrameRef;
    private MapDrawer mapD;
    private MapView hlavnaMapa; 


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()

        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainWindow()
    {
        initialize();   

    }

    public JFrame getMainFrame()
    {
        return frame;
    }


    public JInternalFrame getMapFrame()
    {
        return mapFrameRef; 
    }







    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JMenuBar menuBarUpper = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBarUpper);

        MenuBasicActions = new JMenu("GPS Settings");
        menuBarUpper.add(MenuBasicActions);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_2 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        MenuBasicActions.add(mntmNewMenuItem_2);

        JMenu DevicesMenu = new JMenu("Devices");
        menuBarUpper.add(DevicesMenu);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_3 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        DevicesMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_3);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_4 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
        DevicesMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_4);

        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBarUpper.add(HelpMenu);



        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {

            }
        });
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_1);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        toolBar.add(btnNewButton_3);
        toolBar.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{btnNewButton_1, btnNewButton}));

        JInternalFrame mapInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame("New JInternalFrame");
        mapFrameRef=mapInternalFrame;
        mapInternalFrame.getGlassPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(mapInternalFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mapInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
        //mapFrame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{frame.getContentPane(), toolBar, btnNewButton_1, btnNewButton, btnNewButton_2, btnNewButton_3, menuBarUpper, MenuBasicActions, mntmNewMenuItem, mntmNewMenuItem_1, mntmNewMenuItem_2, DevicesMenu, mntmNewMenuItem_3, mntmNewMenuItem_4, HelpMenu}));
        /*Vlastny kod                               */      


        hlavnaMapa=new MapView();
        hlavnaMapa.Init(mapInternalFrame);



        DrawerEventHandler handler=new DrawerEventHandler();
        mapInternalFrame.addMouseListener(handler);
        mapInternalFrame.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
    }

      public class DrawerEventHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
        {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
            {


            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
            {
                mapD=new MapDrawer(hlavnaMapa.getMap());
                Point2D point=new Point2D.Double(event.getX(),event.getY());
                mapD.addWaypoint(mapD.pointToGeo(point));
                System.err.println(event.getX()+"  "+event.getY());


            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        } 

}
```

MapDrawer class:

```
package soft;



import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapViewer;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.GeoPosition;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.TileFactoryInfo;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.Waypoint;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.WaypointPainter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.mapviewer.util.GeoUtil;


public class MapDrawer 
{

    private JXMapViewer view;
    private JXMapKit mapRef;
    private Set waypoints;
    //private BufferedImage img;
     //img = ImageIO.read(new File("D://workspace//GPS Admin Software//resources//iconPerson.jpg"));

    public MapDrawer(JXMapKit mapa)
    {
        mapRef=mapa;
        waypoints = new HashSet();
    }

    public Point2D geoToPoint(GeoPosition pos)
    {
        return view.convertGeoPositionToPoint(pos);
    }

    public GeoPosition pointToGeo(Point2D point)
    {
        return view.convertPointToGeoPosition(point);
    }


        public void addWaypoint(GeoPosition geo) {
            //create a Set of waypoints



            waypoints.add(new Waypoint(geo.getLatitude(),geo.getLongitude()));

            //create a WaypointPainter to draw the points
            WaypointPainter painter = new WaypointPainter();
            painter.setWaypoints(waypoints);
            mapRef.getMainMap().setOverlayPainter(painter);
        }


}
```

MapViewer class

```
package soft;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit;



public class MapView 
{
    private JXMapKit map;

    public MapView()
    {

        map=new JXMapKit();
        map.setDefaultProvider(org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMapKit.DefaultProviders.OpenStreetMaps);
        map.setDataProviderCreditShown(true);
    }

    public void Init(JInternalFrame container)
    {
        container.add(map);

    }

    public JXMapKit getMap()
    {
        return map;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `JXMapKit` is consuming the mouse events before they reach the internal frame.

Think of mouse events as rain drops and mouse listens as umbrellas.  If an umbrella is opened above you, then the rain drops won't reach you.

Instead of adding the mouse listener to the internal frame, you need to add them to the `JXMapKit` instance

Comment: Ive add it to the JXMapKit and nothing happened

Comment: Finnaly after couplne of hours of trying i found a solution.Instead of doing this           >hlavnaMapa.getMap().addMouseListener(handler);                      i must do this  >hlavnaMapa.getMap().getMainMap().addMouseListener(handler);        .I my idea is good,MouseListener cant gen clicks from dynamic content.Finally ,the clicks works great